# Bootstrap Drop-down Menu in Navbar

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to create a drop-down menu in a navbar, but the sub-menu item is displaying in the main navbar.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-black static-top text-white">
<div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" title="Toggle navigation" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/"><img src="Images/USACE.png" height="70" /></a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" >
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item px-2" style="font-size: large"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/"><strong>HOME</strong></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown px-2" style="font-size: large"><a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"><strong>ABOUT</strong></a>
                <div class="dropdown" >
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">What is an MCX?</a>
                </div>
        </li>
            <li class="nav-item px-2" style="font-size: large"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/"><strong>SERVICES</strong></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item px-2" style="font-size: large"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/"><strong>TRAINING</strong></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item px-2" style="font-size: large"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/"><strong>MEETINGS</strong></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item px-2" style="font-size: large"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/"><strong>TEAM</strong></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item px-2" style="font-size: large"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/"><strong>NEWS</strong></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item px-2" style="font-size: large"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/"><strong>LINKS</strong></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item px-2" style="font-size: large"><a class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/"><strong>CONTACT</strong></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

The about is the drop-down menu. Can you help me with this?